# How to sort a CSV with quoted fields (that may contain the separator)

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, posix

In a shell script I'm trying to sort a CSV file. Some fields may contain the separator and are quoted to handle this correctly. Let's say I have a file with:

```
"2",D,Clair
1,R,Alice
"3","F","Dennis"
2,"P,F",Bob
```

I want to sort this on the first colum, then the third. The result should be:

```
1,R,Alice
2,"P,F",Bob
"2",D,Clair
"3","F","Dennis"
```

There may also be escaped double quotes in the fields. In general, the CSV will conform to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

I tried to do this with a `sort -t , -k 1,1 -k 3,3` but that doesn't work, because `sort` isn't aware of the special meaning of quotes in CSV. I couldn't find a way to make `sort` behave this way. Perhaps I should use another command, but I can't find any.

How to sort my CSV?

Comment: You could probably write a complex `awk` script to deal with the CSV format oddities but why not just use something that has built-in facilities to deal with CSVs in an elegant manner like Python?

Comment: @zwer Because it seems a bit extreme to learn a new programming language for this one problem. I was hoping there is a command or script that does the job, but if you can solve it in a different way then please post an answer. I'd be very interested.

Comment: If it can be really any CSV complying to RFC 4180, the quoted strings may even contain newlines and other nasty stuff. I certainly would not do it on the shell level. Use a programming language which comes with a CSV parser and a sort function (I'm using Ruby, but AFIK Perl and Python would do equally well). You say that you don't want to learn a **new** programming language, but to be honest, if you **only** can do posix shell and nothing else, you will sooner or later get into trouble. You should know at least one versatile scripting language too.

Comment: @user1934428 Ok, how about only commas?

Comment: To be honest, I would even consider the case "comma inside quoted strings" as too tedious when it comes to pure shell programming, in particular since you want tos stay within the limitations of posix shell.

Comment: @user1934428 Fair enough. If you have an alternative, I'd be very interested. Non-posix, Python, Perl, awk... it's mainly about finding the "best" solution to this problem. I'm sure more people will benefit from a good solution. Unfortunately I have too little knowledge of Python and Perl to be of much value there.

Comment: I get exactly the expected result with sort -t , -k 1,1 -k 3,3

Comment: @ctac_ Can you elaborate? When I sort the lines from my question I get the following order: line 1, line 3, line 2, line 4. This is because in ASCII `"` comes before the numbers. If I remove all quotes except those around `P,F` I get: line 2, line 1, line 4, line 3. This is because it sees `F"` as the third column. The correct order is: line 2, line 4, line 1, line 3.

Comment: @Rinke : Back when I started with Perl, I spent about 4 hours learning something about the language before I actually used it for a concrete problem. Of course the program was terribly written, but it did the job. With Ruby, it took maybe a bit over one our to learn before I could use it at least somehow. If you spend just a couple of hours now for learning the basics of such a language, it will pay back later whenever you have to solve a problem which is too cumbersome for shell programming.

Comment: @Rinke elaborate no, I don't know enough about that. I try on Windows7 with busybox and i get the same result as yours. What I see, on man sort there is ***  WARNING  ***  The locale specified by the environment affects sort order. Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values. My system is Linux debian-linux 4.13.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.13.13-1 (2017-11-16) x86_64 GNU/Linux. I have LANG=fr_FR.utf8. If i try LC_ALL=C sort -t , -k 1,1 -k 3,3 , I get your output.

Comment: @Rinke   you can take a look to this thread https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do/87763#87763 . If you want your sort OK, perhaps you must speak french.

Comment: If you're still interested in how to get this done, consider using [CSVfix](https://neilb.bitbucket.io/csvfix/manual/csvfix16/csvfix.html?Usage.html) — that's the manual which has an entry for `sort`; the repo seems to be at https://bitbucket.org/neilb/csvfix.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the excellent [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) for the job:

```
$ xsv sort --no-headers --select 1,2 input.csv
1,R,Alice
2,D,Clair
2,"P,F",Bob
3,F,Dennis
```

[csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can also do it:

```
$ csvsort --no-header-row --columns 1,2 input.csv
a,b,c
1,R,Alice
2,D,Clair
2,"P,F",Bob
3,F,Dennis
```